# Matlab's Data Import returning strings / non-strings inconsistently?

Tags: string, matlab, import, nan, import-from-excel

I have 2 almost identical .xlsx files that I want to import into Matlab.

Problem:

**When importing File 1 as table format, I do get NaNs.**

[image]

**When importing File 2 as table format, I do get 'NaN's instead of NaN, which is annoying.**
[image]

How can I solve the problem with File 2, and still keep the same matrix dimension?

File 1 screenshot:
[image]

File 2 screenshot:
[image]

Comment: how does your code for reading the xls-files look like?

Comment: @bushmills, I use the manual "import button" in Matlab usually. Other than that I tried also some code, but without success. `Hello = readtable('PFR24weeks.xlsx', 'TreatAsEmpty', 'NaN');`

Comment: Are you sure the `NaN` cells are formatted the same in File1 and File2 in Excel? Try copying a `NaN` cell from File1 and pasting it into the relevant places in File2, then save and import again. Any change?

Comment: @Wolfie, I tried this one to make sure it's the same format. No change unfortunately